# Authorizing App Scritp Trigger in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to set up a trigger in for a App Script in a googlesheet, but I get the following message: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l6pq.png)

I have checked my pop-up settings and it's not blocking any pop-ups:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kjEG.png)

So I don't know what to do.

Any suggestions would be really appreaciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of a trigger do wish to create?  You can do it programmatically if you wish.

Comment: If the error is unrelated, ping me back with @TheMaster